next.config.js file had redirection and the redirection still works in other projects
I had a project that managed some redirections in my next.config.js file. which was something like this:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  basePath: process.env.BASEPATH,
  redirects: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/fa/panelManagement/rolesList',
        permanent: false,
        locale: false
      },
      {
        source: '/:lang(en|fa)',
        destination: '/:lang/panelManagement/rolesList',
        permanent: false,
        locale: false
      }
    ]
  }
}

export default nextConfig

Now I'm on a different project and the next.config.js is empty but the redirection still happens.
Is it cached? I tried clearing my browser cache but still didn't fix it.
Does anyone have any idea what I should do?
